# No free space on disk although no files to be found

Tags: 16.04, disk-usage

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and just ran into this issue: I have almost no files on my system to be found, there should be only the system files plus a few MB of my data. But all the system monitoring tools are saying I have a few MB of free space out of 200GB. I don't understand where all the space is. So I wanted to repair the system by a clean reinstall, unfortunately I cannot do it because I have not enough space to download an image of ubuntu.

So what can I do to recover at least some space to be able to do the reinstall?

The problematic partition seems to be `/dev/sda4`.

```
df -x squashfs -x tmpfs -h -T

Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs  7,8G     0  7,8G   0% /dev
/dev/sda4      ext4      177G  177G  130M 100% /
/dev/sda3      vfat      512M   18M  495M   4% /boot/efi
```

I'm also facing another problem with my system, it could be relevant to this one - when I want to do something which includes working with archives, it takes forever. Now I don't know which commands specifically ( probably `apt update` or `upgrade`), as I don't have disk space to run these kind of commands, so I cannot give more info about that :-)

```
sudo du -hs /* 2>/dev/null | sort -hr | head

159G    /var
8,3G    /usr
7,7G    /home
2,6G    /snap
808M    /lib
734M    /opt
168M    /boot
94M /core
15M /etc
13M /sbin
```

Comment: Let us see your disk usage. Please [edit] your post and add the output of `df -x squashfs -x tmpfs -h -T`.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. Please now run `sudo du -hs /* 2>/dev/null | sort -hr | head`. This will show the Top-10 of disk usage per directory.

Comment: I'm not sure if it takes so long or the command is hanged. I tried three times, still the same...

Comment: Just wait. The command scans your whole disk. This may take a while, especially if it's a HDD (not SSD).

Comment: You were right, I updated the question with the output.

Comment: So `/var` is the culprit and we are getting closer. Run again with `sudo du -hs /var/* 2>/dev/null | sort -hr | head -5` to get the Top-5 in `/var`. You may repeat that step for suspicious directories. Alternatively you can issue `sudo find /var -type f -printf '%s\t%p\n' | sort -nr | head` to directly find the 10 largest _files_ below `/var`.

Comment: So it seems to be docker: `157G /var/lib/docker`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with _docker_ but [found](https://www.google.com/search?q=ubuntu+docker+free+space) this https://success.docker.com/article/no-space-left-on-device-error Maybe it's worth a try.

Comment: I solved it with `docker rmi $(docker images -aq --filter dangling=true)`. Thank you for your help.